# Cost function for image segmentation

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, image-processing, signal-processing, image-segmentation

I am currently working on image segmentation based on superpixels. My input is a data matrix that contains stixels (rectangular superpixels that span an entire column). In the matrix I have stixel ID, the segment number, the height (in pixels), a label (whether it is an obstacle or ground) and a disparity value obtained from a stereo camera system. I am looking to implement a system as the one described in this paper:

Erbs, Witte, Scharwaechter, Mester, and Franke.
*Spider-based Stixel object segmentation.*
Intelligent Vegicles Symposium.
([ieeexplore](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6856396), [researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/271456258_Spider-based_Stixel_object_segmentation))

In that paper they have defined the following cost function:
$$ p(Z^t|\theta_{map}^t, L^t) \times p(L^{t-1}|Z^t,L^t) \times p(L^t) \times p(\theta_{map}^t|L^t) \times \text{constant}$$
where $ t $ is the frame number, $ \theta $ is an object parameter vector, $ Z $ is a matrix that contains the data of each segment and $ L $ is a labeling that assigns each stixel to a specific object. There they infer simultaneously the parameter vector and the label vector.
Furthermore they affirm that
$L^*$ maximizes $ p(L^t|L^{t-1},Z^t) $.

However, they have enough frames that they can use velocity of the objects in addition to the spatial position. Also, they are using the previous labels in their optimization function. I must implement this on single images, so I don't have the information of previous labels or the speed term.

I have tried to adapt their expression under my additional constraints, but I am at a loss when it comes to replacing the temporal dependencies and the labelling dependencies. Would then my $L^*$ depend purely on $Z^t$? And if that is so, how should my optimization function look like?

Comment: So I've been familiarizing myself with MRFs these last couple of days and have come upon what may be a solution. In their work Erbs et al. have enough frames to use motion and from there comes the dependency on time of the labels. However wouldn't it be equivalent (or at least a remedy) to iterate over the same image until a minimum is reached? Also, are there any popular or common potential functions for the cliques used in image segmentation?